# error with UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have the following things:

**in header file**

```
 UITableView *catalogTable;
 UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

**implementation file**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    catalogTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    catalogTable.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:171/255.f green:171/255.f blue:171/255.f alpha:220/255.0];

    catalogTable.layer.cornerRadius=15;
    scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    scrollView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:109/255.f 
                                                   green:114/255.f 
                                                    blue:114/255.f 
                                                   alpha:0.65/1.0].CGColor;
}
```

The problem is that I can't run this as I have error at these lines:

```
catalogTable.layer.cornerRadius=15;
scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
```

saying that:`Property cornerRadius not found on object of type CALayer.`

I don't know what to do with this...and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
The strangest thing is that I copied the code from another class where it worked.I copied the whole thing and out of no where came this error.Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To eliminate that error you need to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` header in your file. Without that header compiler can't access information about CALayer class and the properties it has.

P.S. just in case - you'll also need to link with `QuartzCore.framework` to make things work

Answer (score 2):

As like @Vladimir said,add the following line

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```